# Inequality for Kolmogorov's statistics

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Prove that for a sample from the general distribution $F$, for any $t ∈ [0, 1]$ following inequality holds:
$\textbf{P}\{\sup_{y}|F^{*}_n (y) − F(y)| > t\} \leq \textbf{P}\{\sup_{0\leq y\leq1}|G^{*}_n (y) − y| > t\}$.

Where $F^{*}_n (y)$ - empirical distribution function for general distribution, $G^{*}_n (y)$ - empirical distribution, built on sample from uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$.

I noted, that $y$ on the right side is cdf for uniform distribution, so Glivenko-Cantelli says that both supremum approach a.s. $0$,  as n becomes large. I had an idea, that the first supremum approaches faster than the second. But I don't know how to prove that or maybe there is another approach. Also for $y$s near $1$ or $0$, this becomes equality as probability becomes zero.

Comment: I suspect you get equality for a continuous $F$